# Custom BottomNavigationView Interactive options layout Fragments

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, bottomnavigationview

I recently put my hands on Android development and hence have to ask here a query that I have.

In my test app I have a BottomNavigationView, which has 3 options to click. I have seen in many apps that if a selection is tapped it further slides up another sub menu. I couldn't find enough information about this feature.

Looking for a direction if anyone has came across such requirement in the past.

Comment: show any picture or something what you actually want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is deprecated now. look at [say goodbye to menu button](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html.)

if you still want to perform some action on navigation buttons, Override onBackPressed method in your activity so that you are able to perform some action on click of back button of bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks. But so many apps like Ola and Uber does that.. Like when tap on an option on bottom category menu, they show further sub options lets say car models by sliding up a sub menu.